# Python: output contents of for loop to a file - currently outputting last row only

Tags: python, redirect

I have a file which looks like so that I want to transpose:

```
ID_1 S1 S2 S3
SNP1 1 0 1
SNP2 2 1 0
SNP3 1 0 1
```

I have made the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Script to transpose a large file

import os
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    m=[]
    for line in f:
        m.append(line.strip().split(" "))
    for row in zip(*m):
    result = " ".join(row)
    with open('transposed.txt','w') as output:
        output.write(result)
```

I am a bit lost as to how to save this output to a new file. I could write:

```
python script.py file_to_transpose.txt > transposed_file.txt
```

But I want to find a way to do this within the script. 
The expected output is:

```
ID_1 SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
S1 1 2 1
S2 0 1 0
S3 1 0 1
```

However, my current script only allows me to look obtain the last row

```
S3 1 0 1
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Any basic Python tutorial will tell you how to write to a file, please clarify what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to write to a file is something like this:

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write('some string')
```

If you do that in your script, and replace the final print statement with `output.write(" ".join(row))` you ought to get the result you're after unless I've misunderstood you completely.

EDIT: The question has been completely changed, possibly based on the above part of my answer.  I'll try to answer the new question here:

The problem now is that you open the file anew each time you write to it, which creates a new file and gets rid of the old one.  Hence you only get the last line printed.  Open the file only *once* and write to it several times, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Script to transpose a large file

import os
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f, open('transposed.txt','w') as output:
    m=[]
    for line in f:
        m.append(line.strip().split(" "))
    for row in zip(*m):
    result = " ".join(row)
    output.write(result)
```

If you absolutely need to open the file several times (e.g. if you run the entire script several times and need to continue working on the same output), open it in append mode instead of write mode:

```
with open('transposed.txt', 'a') as output:
    output.write('This line will be appended at the end of the file\n')
```